# Gulp html layout plugin

Tags: html, layout, gulp, static-site

I've got very simple problem: 3 static pages with the same layout. So I want to split layout and content + inject some data to layout (like page title) while compiling. Can you suggest me appropriate gulp plugin? I found [gulp-pagemaki](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-pagemaki) - it's exactly what I want except it doesn't work and I don't need markdown compilation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[gulp-html-extend](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-html-extend) solved my problem. It has some disadvantages but it works. [Here is very good sample](https://github.com/drumrollhq/eak-web) of using gulp-html-extend and other plugins like `gulp-usemin` (note: they use [patched version](https://github.com/drumrollhq/eak-web/blob/master/package.json) of `usemin`)